# Move application between monitors in dual screen setup

Tags: 10.10, multiple-monitors

I have dual screen setup for my Ubuntu 10.10 machine,

But whenever I try to move an application to another screen by dragging it, it moves to another workspace in my primary monitor instead of second screen.

Am I missing something here? Is there any way to drag my application to another screen instead of another workspace?

I'm using Gnome and Nvidia graphics card.

Comment: It might be useful to include what graphics driver (and maybe special configuration) and what window manager you are using, or if you don't know the WM, what desktop environment (GNOME, KDE, ...) and whether or not you have desktop effects enabled.

Comment: Please add information about how you set up the dual monitors, then this question will be more answerable.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds very much like you have a dual-xscreen setup. There are a few dual-monitor setups:

1. Twinview
2. Dual xscreen

Twinview is the setup where you can drag windows between monitors. In this setup, both monitors are part of what we call an "xscreen".

In Dual xscreen, each monitor is a seperate xscreen, which means they are completely seperate. You can open apps on each monitor, but can't move them between them. You can also do things like run different window managers on each monitor.

It sounds like you are using this setup. What graphics driver are you using?